# Can't install Xubuntu 20.10 on my old Toshiba laptop BIOS mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu

I can't install Xubuntu on my old Toshiba A660-13T laptop (1TB SSD upgraded recently… and 8 GB of RAM). I always get the same message before the installation: NO EFI System Partition was found.

It has Windows 10 64bit installed yesterday and now I'm stuck at dual boot Xubuntu installation. I've tried to install it several times following all guides found here and google without lucky yet. Can't find what it is going wrong with it really.

Even though my system doesn't support UEFI and Windows 10 is installed in BIOS mode. In my BIOS's boot menu, there was only one option: to boot from USB HDD

As the laptop doesn't have USB boot option, I've to burn Windows 10 64bit (8 GB) downloaded with MediaCreationTool in a dual-layer DVD. And do the same thing with a regular DVD for Xubuntu 20.10.

The laptop firmware is BIOS not UEFI so why is the installer asking about EFI partition ?

Here below I post a some screenshots about the fatal error on Grub installation and the list of partitions done manually.

https://ibb.co/G3Xx9JG

https://ibb.co/1J5r948

https://ibb.co/YcwMBFY

The laptop is too old (2008) so it's BIOS and not UEFI firmware… so this is the first time I'm facing this issue since Ubuntu 6.06. So please help me out

Comment: You must select to install grub on disk mbr.

Comment: The issue it's related to a bug on Xubuntu 20.10 release here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...r/+bug/1891324

So I'm going to try to install Xubuntu 20.04 then upgrade to 20.10.

PROBLEM IS SOLVED ¡¡

Many thanks to all the replies!

Appreciate